# convert character into arithmetic operator without using switch case i.e., convert '+' to +

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    char c;
    int op;
    int a=10,b=20,sum;

    scanf("%c",&c);
    if(c=='+')
      op=1;
    else if(c=='-')
      op=2;
    else if(c=='*')
      op=3;

    switch(op)//here i used switch but i don't want to use it
    {
       case 1: sum=a+b;
               break;
       case 2: sum=a-b;
               break;
       case 3: sum=a*b;
                break;
    }
       printf("%d",sum);

}
```

output should be 30 when c contains c
sum should contain 30
acb should be evaluated to a+b and it should contain  30

Comment: your `if/else` is already completely useless, you should just use your `c` in the `switch(c)` and have the cases with `'+'` etc. Then for your question, why would you do that? The `switch` statement is in the language for a reason. If this is just some obscure assignment that you have, why should we sove that for you, where you seemingly already know how to avoid the `switch` with `if/else` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could simply do this:

```
void main()
{
    char c;
    int a=10,b=20,sum;
    scanf("%c",&c);
    sum=(c=='+')?(a+b):((c=='-')?(a-b):((c=='*')?(a*b):0));
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Don't be confused with the line `sum=(c=='+')?(a+b):((c=='-')?(a-b):((c=='*')?(a*b):0));`. It actually does this:

```
if(c=='+')
    sum=a+b;
else
{
    if(c=='-')
        sum=a-b;
    else
    {
        if(c=='*')
            sum=a*b;
        else
            sum=0;
    }
}
```

The operator (?:) is called Conditional (ternary) operator.

Syntax:

```
condition ? expr_if_condition_is_true : expr_if_condition_is_false
```

If the condition is true, expression1 will be returned. Else expression2 will be returned. As you can see, there are 3 nested conditional operators are used in that line.

Read more about conditional operator [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx).

Comment: Correct, but, sorry to state this, not nice.

Comment: @alk: I know, it lacks readability but improves simplicity. Moreover, it fits the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not saying it's a *good* way of doing things, but you could have something like:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*fn)(int, int);
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

int main(void) {
    int a = 10, b = 20, sum;
    char c;
    fn f[256] = {NULL};

    f['+'] = add;
    f['-'] = subtract;
    // etc

    scanf("%c", &c);
    fn fn = f[(int)c];
    assert(fn != NULL);
    sum = fn(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Realistically, though, just go with a `switch` statement.

Comment: +1 for the array approach.  Note: suggest `f[(unsigned)c]` as since `char` is typically signed and should a user magically type in a `char` in the range -128 to -1, `f[(int)c]` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible is usually too strong a word when it comes to C. And it is always too strong when it comes to functional programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*ops[5])(int,int);
int mul(int f, int s)  { return f*s; }
int plus(int f, int s) { return f+s; }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ops[0] = &mul;
  ops[1] = &plus;

  printf("%u + %u = %u\n", 5, 10, ops['+' - 42](5, 10));
  return 0;
}
```

ops is an array of function pointers (each takes two ints and returns one, which is the type of the standard operations on ints). The ASCII code for the '*' is 42 (what a coincidence!), '+' is 43 and so on. ops[0] = &mul initializes ops to contain the address of the function which multiplies two numbers. Then in the printf ops is indexed by the character code of the operator you want to apply minus the index of the first operator, ie the appropriate function is invoked and the required arguments are passed. Unfortunately, the interval for the four ASCII codes for the four basic artihmetic operators are not continuous (44 is not an operator), so you need 5 elements for the array. The technique is called a lookup table, and it could be made much nicer if I knew how to take the address of the built in + function instead of defining a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c;
int a=10, b=20, result=0;

scanf("%c", &c);
c=='+' && (result = a + b);
c=='-' && (result = a - b);
c=='*' && (result = a * b);
printf("%d", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you can't convert a `char` to an operator. If you want to take different actions depending on the input, you **must** branch.

You can make your switch more compact though, as noted by Matteo Italia and Jens Gustedt.

```
scanf("%c",&c);
switch(c) {
   case '+': sum = a + b; break;
   case '-': sum = a - b; break;
   case '*': sum = a * b; break;
   default: break; /* invalid op? */
}
```

Comment: read the question carefully,answer should be without switch case

Comment: @SaladLfc: I strongly believe a `switch` statement is the most effective way to accomplish this. Instead of blindly just answering *the question*, I believe it's actually more useful to actually try to provide additional insight. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in C/C++ without some switch/if checks.

Comment: Although, you can avoid the first `if`-`else` blocks by using the `switch` directly over `c`.

Comment: The answer is plain wrong as it is shown further down.

Comment: @user1666959: What do you mean? Your lookup-table is just another way of doing branching. The compiler might compile `switch` that way.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution *without switch* (or if or conditional). Two were given independently, therefore the solution is not impossible. BTW, if you examine the generated assembly code, say of gcc, all you will find is an index calculation ie adding a number (the size of the function pointer multiplied by the index) to a starting address.

Comment: @user1666959: Please remember that we are *all* trying to help. If you think Albert is wrong, politely point out **why**, and how you think the answer could be improved. There is no need to post abrasive comments. Cheers

Comment: @user1666959: And you might find exactly the same with switch/if, that's why I was saying that there is no difference. That's branching, just implemented in different ways on the C side. I'm pretty sure that the OP doesn't wanted to know another way of doing branching - I think  he was more searching for something like `eval` in other languages, which is not possible in C.